# How can I get a gradient at two points with Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get the gradient of a function at two different values of the independent variable. I am doing this in the context of modifying the `get_updates` method of Keras' optimizer class.

The relevant section of the code I've written is

```
def get_updates(self, loss, params):
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

    # Copy parameters
    params2 = []
    for p in params:
        params2.append(K.variable(K.get_value(p), name=p.name[:-2] + "_cpy1/"))

    self.weights = [self.iterations]
    for p, p2, g in zip(params, params2, grads):
        v = - self.lr * g  
        new_p = p + 0.5*v # Intermediate/Partial step
        new_p2 = p2 + v   # Reference point for 2nd Gradient

    grads2 = self.get_gradients(loss, params2)
    ....
```

The error I get when I execute this code is

```
  File "/home/me/Projects/RungeKutta/rk_optimizers2.py", line 86, in get_updates
    grads2 = self.get_gradients(loss, params2)
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 91, in get_gradients
    raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

The problematic section of code from Keras's optimizers.py is:

```
def get_gradients(self, loss, params):
    grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
    if None in grads:
        raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
                         'Please make sure that all of your ops have a '
                         'gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). '
                         'Common ops without gradient: '
                         'K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.')
```

In my case, `K` corresponds to Tensorflow. So, the corresponding code for `gradients` is:

```
def gradients(loss, variables):
    """Returns the gradients of `loss` w.r.t. `variables`.

    # Arguments
        loss: Scalar tensor to minimize.
        variables: List of variables.

    # Returns
        A gradients tensor.
    """
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
```

Why do I get the error I see? How can I get a gradient at the first projected updated parameter so that I can get a final update using the average of the gradient at the starting point and the gradient at an (initially) projected end point?